# What properties of a curve fail to hold when it is not regular?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I have been studying differential geometry lately, and in my text (DoCarmo), he (at least at the moment) is only addressing the properties of a curve when they are regular, and hasn't really mentioned why nor what changes when the curve is not regular.

To much dismay, there is a problem in the text which reads as follows

> A regular parametrized curve $\alpha$ has the property that all its tangent lines pass through a fixed point.
>
> a) Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is a (segment of a) straight line
>
> b) Does the conclusion still hold if $\alpha$ is not regular?

I proved a) as follows:

WLOG, Assume $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc-length.

Say the point which the tangent lines pass through is $c$. Then $\exists \lambda: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \ $ such that
$$\alpha(s) + \lambda(s) \alpha'(s) = c$$
I assumed $\lambda(s)$ was differentiable, which made sense to me on an intuitive level, though I have no real justification for. Differentiating:

$$\alpha'(s)(1 + \lambda'(s)) + \lambda(s)\alpha''(s) = 0$$
Since $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha''(s)$ are orthogonal, this requires
$$\lambda'(s) = -1 \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \ \alpha''(s) = 0 \implies k(s) = 0$$

Using either of these will give me that $\alpha(s)$ is the parametrization of a straight line.

However, I fail to see exactly where I implemented the regularity. I feel as though the conclusion likely fails for b), but am unsure where exactly it fails.

> So what exactly does regularity give us here that being singular does not?

Comment: Think about what your condition $\alpha(s) + \lambda(s)\alpha'(s) = c$ means at a singular point of $\alpha.$ Does this really follow from the given property of $\alpha$?

Comment: Even if we amend this by adding an additional assumption regarding singular points, there is another issue: your assumption that $\lambda$ is differentiable is no longer valid. (When you assume $\alpha'\ne 0,$ you can simply rearrange the equation $\alpha + \lambda \alpha' = c$ and take norms to show that $\lambda$ is as smooth as $\alpha'$ is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a curve is not regular, it cannot -in general- be parametrized by the arc length. For instance, consider a $C^ 2$  curve c, which for $t\in [-1,0]$ describe the horizontal segement $[-1,0]\times \{0\}$, by the law $(t^3,0)$ then for $t>0$ the vertical segment $ \{0\}\times [0,1]$, by the law $(0,t^3)$. This curve is $C^2$, not regular, and all its tangent lines pass through the origin.

Comment: Thank you, that counterexample is helpful. Follow up: They seem to be taking the "parametrized by arc length" as a given condition. If a non-regular curve is (able to be) parametrized by arc length, would the conclusion then hold?

Comment: If the curve admits a $C^1$-parametrization by arc length, the result is correct. Let us parametrize the curve in polar coordinate centered at the point where all tangent pass. Let $M(s)= \rho(s) \exp i \varphi(s)$, then by an easy calculation, the tangent pass through the origin iff $\varphi '(s)=0$, and the result follows.